# VS Code: Highlight modified files with SVN extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way in VS Code to highlight files that change regarding to svn? 
Git style, so I can see the change status of my files on the fly.
I am used to using native extension with Git and it highlights modified files by default.

I am using SVN extension from `johnstoncode.svn-scm`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this feature is experimental so far. To enable SVN status in your file explorer:

- Open the file: `<vscode path>\resources\app\product.json`
- Find `extensionAllowedProposedApi`
- Append `"johnstoncode.svn-scm"` in the array

For example, change:

```
{
  "extensionAllowedProposedApi": [
    "ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare"
  ]
}
```

to

```
{
  "extensionAllowedProposedApi": [
    "ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare", "johnstoncode.svn-scm"
  ]
}
```

Source: [official docs of the extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnstoncode.svn-scm)

Comment: I cannot find `<vscode path>\resources\app\product.json` anywhere in my installation

Answer (score 1):

Adding this answer because it would have saved me an hour. This question came up as the top result when I was trying to find out how to enable this feature.

The entire feature has been removed from the SVN plugin since version 2, so you can't enable it anymore. Tough luck! This appears to be because it used an experimental vscode API that was causing problems for some users. See the following issues on the GitHub repo: [#34](https://github.com/JohnstonCode/svn-scm/issues/34), [#632](https://github.com/JohnstonCode/svn-scm/issues/632), [#675](https://github.com/JohnstonCode/svn-scm/issues/675), [#740](https://github.com/JohnstonCode/svn-scm/issues/740) and the PR that removed the functionality: [#690](https://github.com/JohnstonCode/svn-scm/pull/690).